# How long after daily puja do you put off the diya?

Tags: puja

Cannot keep the ghee lamp burning all day/night.
So how long do you typically wait after putting off your diya after puja is over?
Does the scriptures say anything on this topic?

Comment: One lamp needs to burn as long s the Puja is not over .. it can be put off after the Puja is complete. Can't find any scriptural reference for that but this is how it is done.